# Working on a app and a external library in parellel with Android Gradle plugin

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

I searched through Gradle docs, but it only focused on working on subprojects at the same time. I am wondering if it's possible to work on an Android app project and a external library it uses at the same time.

Using Android Maven plugin and IntelliJ, this works perfectly, because you can just add the library pom.xml to IntelliJ, and IntelliJ will automatically compile the library using the source code on file system instead of using existing jars in repositories.

Comment: This blog has adds Actionbarsherlock. You will need a similar procedure.

http://www.ashokgelal.com/2012/12/setting-up-intellij-idea-12-with-maven-actionbarsherlock-roboelectric-androidannotations/

Comment: @mipreamble The blog post seems to deal only with Maven, which I am familiar with. My question is about using Gradle, which Google announced during Google IO 2013.

Comment: I was trying to show you how you can add library to the project without maven and still work on it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a settings.gradle file at your project root and then a build.gradle file in both your Android app module and your external library module.

Your settings.gradle file should look like this:

```
include '<app_module>'
include '<library_module>'
```

Your library module build.gradle should look something like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    buildToolsVersion "17.0"
    compileSdkVersion 17

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

Your main app build.gradle should look something like this:
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile project(':<lib_module>')
}

android {
    buildToolsVersion "17.0"
    compileSdkVersion 17

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this possible with the library not living inside the directory of the main project? I don't see how Gradle would know about the library. What would you put in place of ':<lib_module>'?

Comment: Sorry, my answer wasn't formatted correctly. You should include your library in your settings.gradle file. That's how your main app will know about it. In place of <lib_module>, you'd put the name of the root directory of your library module.

Comment: To use it that way, I am guessing the lib_module must be a subdirectory? It wouldn't be good to put full absolute path to the library source code even if that were possible.